# Isomorphism between basic forms on principal bundle and forms on the associated vector bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, principal-bundles

$P$  is a principal $G$-bundle, $ρ:G→GL(V)$ is a representation, and $E$ is the associated vector bundle of $P$, so $E=(P×V)/G$ with the right action $(p,v)⋅g=(p⋅g,ρ(g^{−1})v)$.

I have read that there is an isomorphism between the basic $V$-valued forms on $P$, and $E$-valued forms on $M$:

\begin{equation}
Ω^k_{\text{bas}}(P,V)\stackrel\sim\to Ω^k(M,E)
\end{equation}
I don't see how they are isomorphic. What is the explicit isomorphism, and why is it an isomorphism?